# Cannot move out of captured variable in an `Fn` closure

Tags: rust

I am pretty much new to rust-lang. I am trying to create my first program, and i am just lost with the ownership/borrowing of rust-lang.

That is my code:

```
let core: PackageCore = package_core::init();
let html = include_str!("./html/index.html");

rouille::start_server("0.0.0.0:44", move |request| {
    core.send_command();
    return Response::html(html.clone());
});

core.start();
```

And that is my error:
[image]

Probably someone can help me here :)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I've indicated where the issue is on your snippet:

```
let core: PackageCore = package_core::init();
let html = include_str!("./html/index.html");

rouille::start_server("0.0.0.0:44", move |request| {
    core.send_command(); // <-- this is where you moved
    return Response::html(html.clone());
});

core.start(); // <-- but you need it here outside of the closure
```

You `move` the `core` inside the closure, but then you call `start()` outside it. That's not possible; it is either moved inside, or it is outside. To get around it, you can either wrap it in a structure that allows multiple pointers to it to exist (`Arc` or `Rc` being the prime candidates), and if I'm right and `start()` requires `&mut self`, you'll need a structure guaranteeing interior mutability (`Mutex`, `RwLock` or `RefCell` being some of the candidates) to allow you to temporarily acquire a mutable reference to it.

Comment: I need to know if your `PackageCore`, particularly the `start()` or `send_command()` fns actually require mutability

Comment: @KhadimFall and while we are at it, is there anything that prevents you from reversing the order of invocation (as in, `start()` then listen)

Comment: Start needs mut and reversing order should be possible :)

Comment: Then if you reverse the order of calls (i.e. `start` before `listen`) you'll be able to `move` the core straight in, assuming no dangling references to `core` anywhere else and nothing else needs to change :-)

Comment: Actually i have this: `let _ = core.thread.unwrap().join();` at the very bottom of the script.

Comment: Yeah, that indicates there's some structural weaknesses in the way you laid out what `PackageCore` does. What do you need to `start()` if you then randomly grab the thread to `join` it?

Comment: ye idk anyting about rust basically. At start i create a tcp connection. I dont want to close the application so i wait for the listining thread :)

Comment: Okay. I've read into what `rouille` is and how it works, and there are issues there too. `start_server` never returns. So even if your code was sane, `start()` would never get called.

Comment: ahhh okay i got it, so i can actually start before rouille and then just start_server and the program will stay open right ? Sorry for spamming comments

Comment: still giving me: `cannot move out of captured variable in an Fn closure`
after i moved start to the top and removed the join.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't anything else using (directly or through a reference held elsewhere) `core`?